# can devices with bluetooth 4.0 and 3.0 or older interact with 2.0+EDR i.e send the command to be executed and recieve the output produced?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to communicate with a device with bluetooth 2.0+EDR type using a android device 
i.e I need to send the command to it and get the output from that back to my device

But the problem is i have doubt whether bluetooth versions after 2.0+EDR (2.1,3 and 4) can do this or i must use only the same type to do this...

Are 3.0 and 4.0 backward compatible?
and does backward compatible mean it can interact with all the older versions or a particular version??

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are backwards compatible so you will have no problem.

Note, though, that the bluetooth 4.0 spec includes the addition of a new standard - bluetooth LE - which is incompatible with classic Bluetooth.  When people refer to Bluetooth 4 they are typically referring to BLE (though technically Bluetooth 4 includes classic Bluetooth too).

Comment: Thanks alot!! 
so 4.0 and others can interact but with lack of new features. 
Am i correct??

Comment: A BT4 device, using classic bluetooth can interact with older Bluetooth devices.  The new BLE capability of a BT4 device is not compatible with older bluetooth as it is a completely different protocol then classic Bluetooth.